# The variable I increment resets itself when I use another activity to go back to it

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I'm making an app which increment a counter on button click and goes to the next activity at the same time. I made a toast to see if it works and it does.
My app is like this,on the main page you press start and then you're taken to the page where theres a button you can click on which increments a variable and takes you to the next page and so on.When I use the return button on the onscreen menu ,and press the button again it increments,however when I go till the end and go back to the main page and press start again and press on the button it goes back to 1,so it resets itself how do I fix it so that even if the start button it pressed the variable should keep its value?

Here's the code for the Main page:

```
public class MainPage extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    hideNavigationBar();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);
    hideNavigationBar();

    Button mainPage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mainPage);
    mainPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainPage.this, HeadBoy.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    });
    ImageButton resultClick = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.resultClick);
    resultClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainPage.this, Results.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    }
```

And this is the code for the second page (the one where the counter increments):

```
public class HeadBoy extends AppCompatActivity {
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
int hb1 ;
int hb2 ;

public  static final String HEAD_BOY_ONE = "count";
public static final String HEAD_BOY_TWO = "counttwo";


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    hideNavigationBar();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_head_boy);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();


    final Button hbone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hbOne);
    final Button hbtwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hbTwo);
    hbone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            increment();

            Intent intent = new Intent(HeadBoy.this,HeadGirl.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    hbtwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(HeadBoy.this,HeadGirl.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    hideNavigationBar();



}
public void increment(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    hb1 = hb1 + 1;
    editor.putInt("headboy1", hb1);

    editor.apply();
      Toast.makeText(this,Integer.toString(hb1),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

This is the last page:

```
public class Results extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    hideNavigationBar();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
     int headboyResult = prefs.getInt("headboy1", 0);
    TextView headBoy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.headBoy);
    headBoy.setText(Integer.toString(headboyResult));

    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.returnButton);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent back = new Intent(Results.this,MainPage.class);
            startActivity(back);
        }
    });
   Button reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetAll);
   reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
      //   editor.putInt("headboy1", 0);
     }
   });
```

Comment: Where you take the value from SharedPreference and set on your textView?

Comment: Could you try to reduce your code to a [mcve]? Have you considered that you create a new activity on your start page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this, you are not reading the stored value for your counter. Each time you recreate your activity, the counter will be initialized to 0.

**Change method as follows:**

```
 public void increment(){
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        hb1 = prefs.getInt("headboy1",0);

        hb1 = hb1 + 1;
        editor.putInt("headboy1", hb1);

        editor.apply();
        Toast.makeText(this,Integer.toString(hb1),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked
Can you tell me how to make a reset button which makes the variable reset to 0?

Comment: @Saisriram Great! Remember to mark it as accepted if it was useful, so that others can benefit too. Just create a button as you are creating `final Button hbone` then on click just set the preference to `0`. `editor.putInt("headboy1", 0);`

Comment: I accepted it,I made a new button and set the onClick to editor.putInt("headboy1",0); But it did'nt work if possible could you post the entire code for that part like you did for the answer.

Comment: @Saisriram did you call `commit()` or `apply()` after that?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry ,fixed it OMG dude ur like a genius .
Last qn but instead of doing the reset on that activity how do I reset the variable  on another activity

Comment: @Saisriram Just move your code new activity. SharedPreferences are specific to an application and not to a particular activity.

Comment: I added the code to the question can you please check it out and tell me how to get it?

Comment: @Saisriram you have to copy `SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);` and 
   `SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();` too. Then call `editor.commit()` or `editor.apply()`